# What the correct RestRequest "Content-Type" for POST-ing an integer or string?

Tags: c#, api, http-headers, restsharp

I'm trying to build a system test for testing an Api endpoint, and i need to enter an integer eg. 124562, instead of a json. I have my .addHeader and .addParameter code as "Application/json", but i suppose that it works when i'm to enter a json string, but in my case it's just a number like "124562". I'm not sure of the correct way. My code is as follows:

```
public RestRequest CreatePostRequest(string paymentid)
{
     var restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
     restRequest.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
     restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", paymentid, ParameterType.RequestBody);
     return restRequest;
}
```

Comment: It seems like you need to create Json with the value inside like `{"paymentid":"124562"}` and pass that.

Comment: @juharr, i thought about that initially, but thought incase there is a way to pass like an integer without creating a json string.

Comment: Since you are specifying that you are sending json in the header then you have to send json.

Comment: Yeah, like i asked, is there a way to pass just an interger without passing a json string? what could that be? "Application/??"

Comment: You have to encode the value somehow.  Either in a file type like json or xml or as an url parameter, but really you have to do whatever the endpoint is expecting for it to work.